# Assigning an array to a struct member in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I wrote this piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo
{
    int foo1[3];
};

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
    struct foo test;
    test.foo1 = a;
    printf("%d\n", test.foo1[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

It gives compile error saying that it cannot convert int * to int[3].

I know that array names will decay into pointers in expressions, but is there a way of suppressing that since I do need an array here?

Comment: `test.foo1=a;` to `memcpy(test.foo1, a, sizeof(test.foo1));`

Comment: well you could write `struct foo test = { {1,2,3} };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the others said, there is not direct assignment operators that will copy an array. You have to use `memcpy()` instead

```
memcpy(test.foo1, a, sizeof(a));
```

This is one source of errors in C because the `sizeof()` needs to be large enough to copy all the data but not too large so as not to overwrite data at `tests.foo1`. The best practice, I would imagine, is to test that both arrays are the same size before doing the `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the basics of C, arrays cannot be assigned.

Comment: I think *copied* would be a better word.

Comment: @ajay, better word or not, assignment *is* the technical term in C for that. (Perhaps your are thinking of the C++ copy operator? A different language.) BTW, arrays can be copied when using `memcpy`.

Comment: `int a = 4; int b; b = a;` What I meant by copy is the last statement *copies* the content of `a` into `b`. Or do we say `a` is assigned to `b`?

Comment: @ajay, the later. In C `=` is the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

In C and in C++ there is no way to assign a value to an whole array. It is also not possible to assign an array the values of an other array (even if the dimension would match).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign arrays in C. However, you can assign objects of user-defined type, even if those contain an array. So peraps rewrite it like this:

```
struct foo a = { { 1, 2, 3 } };

struct foo test;
test = a;
```

Or of course just initialize the object correctly immediately:

```
struct foo test = { { 1, 2, 3 } };
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not first class objects in `C`. You can't copy (assign), compare, pass, or return an array. You copy an array into another array element by element. You also compare two arrays element by element. You pass a pointer to a first element of the array and similarly return a pointer to the first element of a dynamically allocated array. Therefore `test.foo1 = a;` is wrong. You have two choices here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    int foo1[3];
};

int main(void) {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
    struct foo test;
    int len = *(&(test.foo1) + 1) - test.foo1; // length of the array test.foo1
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        test.foo1[i] = a[i];  // copy the array element-wise

    printf("%d\n", test.foo1[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

You can also directly copy all the bytes from the array `a` in `main` to the array `test.foo1` using `memcpy`.

```
memcpy(test.foo1, a, sizeof a);
```

This copies all the bytes of the array `a` into the array `test.foo1`. Therefore the array `test.foo1` must be large enough else it will lead to undefined behaviour or even segfault.